# NullPointerException on Android screen orientation change

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, orientation, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm developing a simple game. To do so, I have a thread that while running invokes a `SurfaceView.draw(Canvas c)`.

This method recalculates objects positions and draws them. Moving objects, when touching a screen limit, have to appear with the same moving direction in the opposite side.

Problem is that if I change the orientation while an object is in the limit, I receive a `NullPointerException` and program crashes.

It also happens if I press the "back" key, which is a different problem.

Anny suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide some code, and some error logs, otherwise we can't guess what your problem is :)

Comment: So your Acitivity is recreated when orientation changes but you do not initialize all members. The NPE gives you the exact line so you'll see which member or variable this might be.